Apache, deny access to all files and subdirectories except index.php
I have this in my httpd.conf but does not work, request is forbidden typing localhost:
<Directory "${DOCUMENT_ROOT}">
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Includes +ExecCGI

    AllowOverride None

    Require all denied

    LimitRequestBody 1024000


    <Files "index.php">
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

I want to deny access to all files and subdirectories except index.php, but I actually get forbidden request from the server when y write http://localhost/.

A better way to do this would be to put index.php in a subdirectory by itself, and then make that subdirectory the DOCUMENT_ROOT.

Finally I've found a solution. Allow index.php files or empty:
<Directory "${DOCUMENT_ROOT}">
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Includes +ExecCGI

    AllowOverride None

    Require all denied

    LimitRequestBody 1024000


    <FilesMatch "^(index\.php|)$">
        Require all granted
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>

